# How to use Data URI from Image as an InputStream?

Tags: java, facebook, image, canvas, base64

I have retrieved the base64 data uri from a html5 canvas. Within my servlet, I would like to decode the data uri and use it as an input stream as shown in "xxx" below. The following coding is for me to post the image in the html5 canvas into my facebook account. I am using restfb.

```
FacebookType publishPhotoResponse = facebookClient.publish("me/photos", FacebookType.class,
BinaryAttachment.with("test.jpeg", getClass().getResourceAsStream("xxx")),
Parameter.with("message", "Test"));
```

How can I achieve that? Thanks.

**Updated** Getting closer but still not working!

In my jsp:

```
var d = document.getElementById('img').src;
window.location.href = "upload?src=" + d;
```

In my servlet:

```
String d = req.getParameter("src");
String head = "data:image/jpeg;base64,";
String base64 = d.substring(head.length()-1);

byte[] buf = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64);
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);

FacebookType publishPhotoResponse = facebookClient.publish("me/photos", FacebookType.class,
BinaryAttachment.with("test.jpeg", is),
Parameter.with("message", "Test"));
```

Is there any errors in my coding as it seems to hit error somewhere within the servlet. I can't view the errors as it is running on a server.

Comment: Ok, I think the problem might lie in the querystring from jsp to my servlet. Do I need to encode the base64 first before setting it in the querystring? I have tried converting my base64 to image using online convertor, it is showing the image good.

Comment: I managed to solve it, indeed is problem with my querystring. I have create a hidden element that stores the data before submitting to my servlet. Thanks for your guides, it helps! Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This needs almost the exact opposite to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10132345/418556)! Or at least, the reverse of it.  It answers `Image` to base 64 `String`, whereas this use-case is `String` to `Image`.

Look to [`javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseBase64Binary%28java.lang.String%29) to get a `byte[]` of the `String`.

Use the `byte[]` to construct a [`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html).

Comment: I have added the following coding... Did I use it correctly?
`byte[] buf = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64);`
`ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);`

Comment: Hi, to ease the readability, I have updated it on my post instead, can someone help me check? Thanks.

Comment: The above coding has no problem, problem lies in my querystring, thanks for your help by the way, cheers.