# How to convert Base64(imageurl) to an image

Tags: java, base64, imageurl

I have to convert image URL into an image.  For that I tried following coding for convert base64 to an image.  While on debugging the code "Bufferedimage image" is always null after `ByteArrayInputStream bis=new ByteArrayInputStream(imagebyte)`. What can I do?

```
   String imageStr = request.getParameter("imgURL");
   BufferedImage image = null;

    try {
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
     byte[] imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageStr);
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
        image = ImageIO.read(bis);
        File outputfile = new File("E:\\saved.png");
         ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);
        bis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: you are trying to decode the URL into an image. The URL tells you where the image is!

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10132345/418556).  If you cannot get it working from that, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

> I have to convert image URL into an image.

If that is your only requirement, then will this do?

```
 URL url = new URL("www.example.com/image.png");
 BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
 File outputfile = new File("E:\\saved.png");
 ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);
```